# What do the parts not in plain English in this Concrobium anti mold product web page mean: "Cas #", "Builder", and "Withheld"?

Tags: mold

This home improvement product company web page about an anti-mold product called Concrobium
https://www.concrobium.com/products/mold-control-spray/ has the following table:

```
Ingredient              Cas #       Function
 
Water                   7732-18-5   Solvent
Sodium Carbonate        497-19-8    Active Ingredient
Trisodium Phosphate     7601-54-9   Builder
Alkali Metal Carbonate  Withheld    Builder
```

Google says the alkali metal carbonates are Li2CO3, Na2CO3i and K2CO3 but returns nothing useful about other terms.

What do the parts not in plain English mean: "Cas #", "Builder", and "Withheld"?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cas%20number

Comment: Withheld is "plain English" for "we're not telling you the CAS number"

Comment: Withheld is also used so you don't make the same thing for 10% of the cost.

Comment: Sodium carbonate already being listed above, it's either lithium carbonate or potassium carbonate or perhaps both.

Answer (score 1):

**Cas number:**
https://www.cas.org/support/documentation/chemical-substances/faqs

> Each CAS Registry Number® (CAS RN®) identifier:
>
> Is a unique numeric identifier Designates only one substance Has no
> chemical significance Is a link to a wealth of information about a
> specific chemical substance

I would guess "Builders" are to give body to the product.

"Withheld" is to protect their brand because they think whatever they are using makes their stuff special and it is a reasonable thing that they don't want to get copied.

I am interested that "sodium carbonate" is the active ingredient.  So mold control by lowering pH via washing soda?  I hope you are not paying a whole lot for this stuff.  You can buy a big box of dry washing soda for $5 and skip paying for water.

Comment: What does "give body to the product" mean? Do you have reason to believe that a solution  of sodium carbonate in water alone would work?

Comment: I figured "builder" gave the stuff some substance so it looks like there is more to it than clear water.  I was surprised that sodium carbonate is used as an antifungal but it makes sense that a strong base would kill things.  As regards a solution of sodium carbonate in water it looks like that is what this is: 1% sodium carbonate.  AT $10/quart on Amazon.